# Conserved current transforming under adjoint

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, conservation-laws, group-theory, representation-theory

If we have a Lagrangian with a global internal symmetry $G$. Why do the conserved currents transform under the adjoint representation of $G$? Is it a general statement (if this is the case, how can we derive it?), or does it depend on the representation of the fields in the Lagrangian?

Comment: Write down these currents, the ensuing charges, and the Lie algebra of those. What do you conclude?

Comment: Look at the operator statements first, and only then worry about matrix elements. I believe you are overthinking something simple, or have misconfigured your question to appear 37 times more trivial than what confuses you.

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward, provided you appreciate the currents and their charges are the vectors (states) of the adjoint, not its transformation matrices/generators.

Ignoring normalizations and superfluous signs, which you may fuss to your satisfaction, and taking your arbitrary representation generator $G^a$ to be hermitean, for a complex scalar field in an *arbitrary representation* whose indices are suppressed, you have something like
$$
j^a_\mu(x)= i ^∗(x)G^ \overset{\leftrightarrow}∂_ (x), ~~~~\leadsto \\
Q^a= \int \!\! d^3x~ j^a_0(x)=i \int \!\! d^3x~ (\pi^*(x) G^a\phi(x) - \phi^*(x)G^a \pi(x) ~).
 $$

Recalling the equal-time commutators, like all commutators here,
$$
[\phi(x),\pi^*(y)]= [\phi^*(x),\pi(y)]=i\delta(\vec x - \vec y) ,
$$
you trivially get
$$
[Q^a, j^b(x)] \\ = -\int \!\! d^3y~ [  (\pi^*(y) G^a\phi(y) - \phi^*(y)G^a \pi(y) ~), (\partial_\mu ^∗(x)G^b (x)- ^∗(x)G^b \partial_\mu(x))]\\
\propto \qquad if^{abc}j^c(x)~~,
$$
up to signs and normalizations you must fix. Note there are no suppressed indices anywhere, anymore! The representation matrix infinitesimally transforming the adjoint vector currents is just the structure constant.

The Lie algebra elements may be in absolutely *any* representation, $G^a$, (you and I are suppressing their indices and those of $\phi$ here), and they obey the very *same* Lie algebra, yielding the *same* $f^{abc}$ in their commutator, irrespective of their representation. They ***need not*** be in the fundamental!  The currents, and hence charges, transform like vectors in the adjoint representation, the generators for this transformation being $if^{a}_{bc}$.

For example, consider the spin 7/2 representation of SU(2), so the three $G^a$ are 8×8 matrices. The three operators $j^a(x)$ and hence, as seen $Q^a$ , are vectors in the spin 1 representation, necessarily, and thus transform by the 3×3 matrices $i\epsilon^{abc}$. This would be evident, as above, by the intercalated commutators of the corresponding $G^a$ in *any representation*!

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to show that the current necessarily transforms under the adjoint without referring to a specific Lagrangian. In particular, I wanted to show that : \begin{equation}
dj_aj_b=f_{abc}j_c
\end{equation}
holds in general. So if I understood well : from the conserved current $j_a$, we build the conserved charge $Q_a$ then using the Ward identities we show that :
\begin{equation}
[Q_a,\phi] = G_a.\phi
\end{equation}
For a field $\phi$ transforming under infinitesimal transformation as : $\phi \rightarrow \phi - i\lambda_aG^a\phi $.

Comment: Then we conclude that the $Q_a$’s are valued in a representation of the Lie algebra (whose group is the representation in which the fields $\phi $ live) and generate the symmetry. But how can we derive that the current are in the adjoint representation of G ? Does it holds only for $\phi $ in the fundamental ?

Comment: Clarified my answer. You *never* specified the fields are in the fundamental. There can be in any representation, and the above calculation goes through identically!

Answer (score 0):

Charges are constructed by integrating currents,
$$
Q^a = \int_\Sigma n^\mu j_\mu^a
$$
$Q^a$ transforms in the adjoint, therefore $j^a_\mu(x)$ must transform in the adjoint.